# The word どういう in this dialogue

Tags: words

> この言葉はどういう意味ですか。
>
> これは「薬屋」という意味です。

What would be a translation for the word どういう and the dialogue? I looked it up on Jisho, but I just get more confused with its meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google says : どういう == What kind of

> What does this word mean?
>
> It means "druggist". (pharmacy)

どういう == How + say --- (if you break it up)